# remove Pi hut / adafruit adjustable PIR plastic cover

Tags: sensor

I have a PIR but there is this massive plastic cover around the sensor, it's also not verry well connected so it keeps falling off... is it safe to just not use the plastic over?

Will be used in a potentially moist environment.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plastic cover is made up of fresnal lenses that focus the infrared energy from a distant source onto the sensor. Depending on your usage you can do without it. If you're looking to detect infrared sources close to the sensor for example.

Comment: Aha, so it's meant to capture motion from a better range or rather from a light source as some sort of long distance tripwire?

Comment: @Havnar - Better range yes, but the lenses focus IR from all directions, so I wouldn't describe it as a trip wire.